# Can replication\save conflicts be identified in Xpages

Tags: xpages

If I know a notes document opened in Xpages has created a replication\save conflict duplicate document and then search for the document ID in Xpages then both (or all) the documents are shown in an Xpage set up with a specific Notes view in my application.  But is there any way I can tell which one is the parent document and which one(s) are the replication response documents?  I need to be able to see this on the Xpages front end and not just in the Notes database backend.

Comment: You can identify the conflict document with the @IsAvailable($Conflict) formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a view with `@IsAvailable($Conflict)` as the selection formula, you can identify conflicts. They have a $REF field which maps to the parent document.

Because XPages allows us to have multiple datasources on an XPage, it should be feasible to open the conflict have dominoDocument datasources for the conflict and the parent document (the non-conflict).

Comment: Thanks for response.  Can I interrogate the $REF field if the view is created using another formula?

Comment: Because of the $REF being a map to the parent UNID does this mean that - if the parent is deleted and the response is retained that there could be problems leter on?

Comment: Good practice is to never delete the parent, if the conflict have correct values you should move them to the parent

Comment: @ThomasAdrian Thanks Thomas.  That is what I thought and have implemented a way that system owner can deal with reversing this

Comment: For my customers I have an xpage that is loaded in the client that display all conflicts and all values that is different, with a click of a button they can remove each conflict. or choose to move it manually to the parent. really handy and easy

Comment: I've always planned to get round to developing something like that for OpenNTF, but too many other things keep getting in the way. Plus displaying some fields possible with OpenNTF Domino API left me scratching my head e.g. Maps of ArrayLists stored as a Java object in a NotesItem.

Answer (score 1):

If your view has the option 'Show response documents in a hierarchy' then your parent document comes always first and right after it all the replication conflicts. You can show the replication conflicts this way:

```xml
<xp:viewPanel
    value="#{view1}"
    id="viewPanel1" 
    var="rowData">
    ...
    <xp:viewColumn
        columnName="yourColumnName"
        id="viewColumn2"
        value="#{javascript:
            if (rowData.getDocument().hasItem('$Conflict')) {
                var parentId = rowData.getDocument().getItemValue('$REF');
                return '[Replication ot Save Conflict]';
            }
            return rowData.getColumnValue('yourColumnName')
        }">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:viewColumnHeader
                value="Unid"
                xp:key="header"
                id="viewColumnHeader2">
            </xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xp:viewColumn>
</xp:viewPanel>
```

Orphan replication conflict documents with deleted parent document don't show up in this kind of view.

If your view has **not** the option 'Show response documents in a hierarchy' set then all replication conflicts would be visible even the orphans. Documents are sorted by the column values so the replication conflicts wouldn't be necessary right beneath the parents document. In this case you might want to show the parent's DocumentUniqueID in addition with the help of `parentId` variable.

Comment: @KnutHermann Thanks Knut.  This is useful but I think I have a fix for this aspect of my issue that allows the system owner to deal with the problem documents

Answer (score 1):

Although previous answers will help, they complicate everything at page level. Get rid of conflicts in their source - so XPage or background code doesn't need to.

In our applications every view used for XPages has selection formula enriched with

```
& !@IsAvailable( $Conflict )
```

That way no matter what code (datasource, component, SSJS, Java, @Formula) in XPage does not need to handle conflicts.

**Edited to answer your question:**

In adition to above, you can have special view with conflicts only (selection of `@isAvailable( $Conflict )`) sorted by `@Text( $REF )` column. You are not able to show any other data for conflict documents.

Then, you can add column that will lookup whether document with specific UNID has any conflict documents and highlight them, show conflict count, or something else.

My two cents though - conflict resolving in Notes client is much clever idea.

Answer (score 0):

All these responses are great but in the end why are conflicts getting generated? There should be logic in the design so that a minimal group of people can edit a document at any one time. If all your users are editor level then re-think your application. Most users should be author access and the use of authors field defines who can edit that document, which might change depending on the workflow status.

Comment: Thanks Howard.  Yes.  I agree.  the application is very complicated - I never built it.  My boss won't allow it to be rebuilt and hence we just have to sort certain aspects.  I think I have a fix for this now.